# How to get TVirtualInterface's invoke method argument names?

Tags: delphi, rtti

I want use dynamic method calling with TVirtualInterface. 
When calling a method, i need parameter names. How to get it? 
I am getting Values and types without any problem.

```
TSimple = class(TVirtualInterface)
  constructor Create(PIID: PTypeInfo);
  procedure DoInvoke(Method: TRttiMethod;  const Args: TArray<TValue>; out Result: TValue);
end;

constructor TSimple.Create(PIID: PTypeInfo);
begin
  inherited Create(PIID, DoInvoke);
end;

procedure TSimple.DoInvoke(Method: TRttiMethod;
 const Args: TArray<TValue>; out Result: TValue);
var
  Arg: TValue;
  ArgType, ArgName: string;
  TempKind: TTypeKind;
begin
   Write('You called the ', Method.Name, ' method ');
   if Length(Args) > 1 then begin
     Writeln('and it has ', Length(Args) - 1,' parameters:');
     for Arg in Args do  begin
       TempKind := Arg.Kind;
       if TempKind <> tkInterface then begin
         ArgName := Arg.ToString;  <<---- Shows : '(TypeName @ 029011B0)' not Name.
         ArgType := Arg.TypeInfo.Name;
         Writeln(ArgName, ' which is of the type ', ArgType);
       end;
     end;
   end else begin
     Writeln(' and it has no parameters.');
   end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Args` does not contain any RTTI type information but is just an array of `TValue`, which contains the actual parameter values passed to the method (`TValue` is similar to a variant).

If you want to query information about the parameter types, you can use the `TRttiMethod` passed to the method to get an array of `TRttiParameter`, which has a property `Name`:

```
var
  Arg : TRttiParameter;
...
for Arg in Method.GetParameters do
  Writeln(Arg.Name);
```